# CSS selector ~ not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a button and I would like to change the css when someone focuses on the input field.

```
html body form div#composite-field input[type=email]:focus ~ html body form div#composite-field input[type=submit] {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #2e4e67;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method='post' class="animate" autocomplete="off">
    <div id="composite-field">
        <input type='email' class='animate' value='' placeholder='Е-mail Адреса'>

        <input type='submit' class='animate' value='>'>
    </div>
</form>
```

As far as I've looked up online, I have the selector setup properly. But for some reason it isn't working.

I'd appreciate another set of eyes to help identify the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Can you put this into something like jsfiddle or codepen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`~` is a general ***sibling*** combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators). Thus, the elements have to be siblings in order for it to be selected.

Based on the HTML you provided, use the following:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/tuf3rr9k/)

```
form div#composite-field input[type=email]:focus ~ input[type=submit] {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #2e4e67;
}
```

You already narrowed the selector down to the `#composite-field` element. After the combinator, `~`, you would just specify the sibling element you are trying to select. You were trying to select a sibling `html` element, and then select the `input[type=submit]` element within it. Since it isn't a sibling of `input[type=email]`, nothing was selected.

Comment: Thank you. It works. So because I already have narrowed down the `form` and `div` I don't need to for the second element contained in the same `div`, correct?